# Only append text to non null values pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the a df which looks like this:

```
|  id | qty  | item |
+-----+------+------+
| 001 |  700 | CB04 |
| 002 |  500 |      |
| 003 | 1500 | AB01 |
```

I want to append text `box` to `df['item']` where items are not null, so the New df will look like the following:

```
|  id | qty  |   item   |
+-----+------+----------+
| 001 |  700 | CB04 box |
| 002 |  500 |          |
| 003 | 1500 | AB01 box |
```

Answer (score 9):

For me working solution without check `NaN`s:

```
df['item'] += ' box'
print (df)
   id   qty      item
0   1   700  CB04 box
1   2   500       NaN
2   3  1500  AB01 box
```

Solutions with check `NaN`s:

Use [`notna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.notna.html) with `loc`

```
df.loc[df['item'].notna(), 'item'] += ' box'
#for oldier pandas versions
#df.loc[df['item'].notnull(), 'item'] += ' box'
print (df)
   id   qty      item
0   1   700  CB04 box
1   2   500       NaN
2   3  1500  AB01 box
```

Or [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['item'] = np.where(df['item'].notna(), df['item'] + ' box',  df['item'])
#df['item'] = np.where(df['item'].notnull(), df['item'] + ' box',  df['item'])
```